# How do I make the jQuerymobile scrollview snap?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I've been trying to implement a mobile site where the user can swipe throught like homescreens on the iPhone. (like swearch.me)

I just can't figure out how to make the screens/pages snap while scrolling.

Of course I'm also open for other suggestions on how to accomplish this.
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the "Scrollview Paging" option in the link you've provided:

> **Scrollview Paging**
>
> A scrollview can be set up so that it scrolls by pages. This feature is only enabled for horizontal or vertical scrollviews. Use `data-scroll="xp"` or `data-scroll="yp"` to turn on paging. The following scrollview pages horizontally.

Snap! There you go!